# FeatureTools deal with aggregation like count(distinct day())

Tags: aggregation, featuretools

I'm dealing with data by featuretools, and after checking the result. I find out that maybe count distinct day() could be better than count(). But I'm new to ft, and couldn't find a way to get these kind of features. Any ideas?

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A01','A01','A02','A02','A02'],'ID2':['B02','B03','B04','B05','B06'],'f1':[1,1,2,2,2],'f2':[9,1,2,3,4],'f3':['click','end',"start",'click','end'],
'mytime':pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-20 14:44:00','2021-01-18 12:30:04','2021-01-13 11:33:31','2021-01-15 18:31:19','2021-01-19 21:09:32'])})
```

```
es = ft.EntitySet(id = 'test1')
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'a', 
                         dataframe = a, 
                         index = 'ID2',
                         time_index='mytime')
es.normalize_entity(base_entity_id='a', 
                    new_entity_id='b', 
                    index = 'ID1', 
                    additional_variables = ['f1'])
```

```
feature_matrix, feature_names = ft.dfs(entityset=es, 
                                       target_entity = 'b', 
                                       max_depth = 6, 
                                       verbose = 1, 
                                       n_jobs = -1, 
                                       chunk_size = 100,
                                       agg_primitives=['count'],
                                       trans_primitives=['day'])
feature_matrix
```

It seems the dfs wouldn't automatically do count after day transforming.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to apply a distinct day transformation and then a count aggregation on top of the transformation.

Featuretools has built-in [Day of the Month](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/generated/featuretools.primitives.Day.html) and [Day of the Week](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/generated/featuretools.primitives.Weekday.html) primitives that may fit for your distinct day transformation.

If you include "count" in `agg_primitives` and "weekday" and "day" in `trans_primitives` for your `dfs` call, `DFS` may generate the features you want automatically (note that aggregation primitives require two dataframes to be linked by a relationship).  Additionally, you could use the `seed_features` parameter in `dfs` to define the feature you want manually (see [documentation](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/guides/tuning_dfs.html#Using-%22Seed-Features%22))

If the built-in primitives do not fit your distinct day transformation, you can write a custom transformation primitive to apply the function you want. [Relevant guide](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/getting_started/primitives.html#Defining-Custom-Primitives)